# Commas surrounding "let alone"

Tags: comma-splices

Is this sentence correct with regard to commas? Especially around "...let alone attain...". Thank you :)

> In a dynamic market, the Central Planning Board would be too slow to significantly approach, let alone attain, equilibrium.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct use of the commas.

Comment: _Let alone_ introduces a comparison clause, and virtually always requires a phrase break, in the form of a comma, in print.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's not quite the same. That question asks what "let alone" means, and takes it as a given that it's surrounded by commas.

Comment: @Barmar: In OP's example, *let alone attain* is effectively a parenthetical "interjection". I expect we've got questions dealing with commas and parenthetical phrases, but it's really just general reference.