# Is a comma after the word introduced by 'let alone' in the middle of a sentence needed?

Tags: british-english, commas

Consider the following British-English sentence:

> It is difficult for the decision-makers to believe, let alone accept(,) that the increased hardware-security would outweigh the production loss caused by security-enhancing measures.

Is the second comma mandatory, forbidden, or optional?  In the optional case: what shift in the meaning does the introduction of the comma (versus its absence) cause?  Justification supported by references would be welcome.

If it has any relation: we use the serial (Oxford) comma throughout the rest of the text.

[OOD](http://www.lexico.com/en/definition/let_alone) provides a single example without a comma:

> Who on earth would be prepared, let alone equipped to take on such a challenge?

But, there is no explanation (and it might even be a typo), so, all bets are off.

Comment: This is obviously a duplicate in an etic sense of ['Commas surrounding “let alone” {duplicate}'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286234/commas-surrounding-let-alone), which was closed as a 'duplicate' (ELU sense) of [the phrase 'let alone'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29878/the-phrase-let-alone).

Answer (score 3):

The second comma is mandatory.

> It is difficult for the decision-makers to believe, let alone
>   accept, that the increased hardware-security would outweigh the
>   production loss caused by security-enhancing measures.

"Let alone accept" is parenthetical in your sentence, i.e. it's an extra piece of information which is not essential in order for the sentence to make sense -- if you remove it, you still have a perfectly correct sentence. Parenthesis is set off by a pair of punctuation marks which can be two commas, two dashes, or two brackets.

Dictionary reference has a more detatiled definition for [parenthesis](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/parenthesis):

> Grammar. a qualifying, explanatory, or appositive word, phrase,
>   clause, or sentence that interrupts a syntactic construction without
>   otherwise affecting it, having often a characteristic intonation and
>   indicated in writing by commas, parentheses, or dashes, as in William
>   Smith—you must know him—is coming tonight.

Comment: Not sure if it's an oversight or a a different understanding. A third possibility is that your sentence could be interpreted in a different way. Who on earth would be prepared [for the end of the world or other catastrophe which we can only know from the overall context], or equipped to take on the challenge. In this case the part after the comma is an afterthought.

Comment: @SConroy In your comment, there should be no comma in the example sentence at all. If you remove the parenthetical information, the sentence should read (without a comma) *Who on earth would be prepared or equipped to take on the challenge?* If you want to make it clear that it's not "(prepared or equipped) to take on the challenge," then you would use two sentences or a dash: (1) *Who on earth would be prepared? Or equipped to take on the challenge?*; or (2) *Who on earth would be prepared—or equipped to take on the challenge?*

Comment: @Jason Bassord. Stylistically I prefer your suggestions too -- I was just trying to find a justification for the authors to have put a single comma in that position.

Comment: We may note that it is annoyingly common – but still wrong – to omit the second comma (or dash) of a parenthesis.

Comment: Please check for duplicates before answering.